# Rendering partial with ajax in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've a simple application that contains post that has many comments.

I can create comments from posts#show with the following form.

```
<%= form_for @comment, :remote => true, :html => {:'data-type' => 'html', :id =>                 'create_comment_form' }, :'data-update-target' => 'comments-container'$
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', :disable_with => 'Please wait...', :class => 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

And then I show the comments with

```
<div id="comments-container">
  <%= render "posts/comments"  %>
</div>
```

which loops through @post.comments.

Is it possible to update @post.comments and rerender the partial when the form is submited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you currently render anything from your `posts#create` action? Either way, you'll want to render a `create.js.erb` (create this file in `app/views/posts/`) like @jvnill says:

```
def create
  # do your thang..
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      # any stuff you want to do when responding to JS
    end
  end
end
```

This will automatically render `create.js.erb`, which should be something like:

```
$('#comments-container').html('<%= escape_javascript(render "posts/comments") %>');
```

Edit - you're getting the problem you describe with `render` because your trying to render from an asset. Put it in your views directory.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do that.  In `create.js.erb`, try

```
$('#comments-container').html('#{escape_javascript render('posts/comments')}')
```

Make sure that whatever instance variables you're using inside the partial is declared.

UPDATE: A better way would be to just append the comment at the end of the div.

Comment: $("#comments-container").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "posts/comments") ) %>");

results in undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x00000002100ae8>:0x00000003515dd0>

Comment: I guess I will return the comments as json and append it, the downside of this is that you lose the benefit of using a partial for formating the comments

Comment: no you can still use a partial for the comments.  inside `posts/comments`, use a partial to render each comment, then use that partial to append to the div.  as for your error, it is weird you're getting that.